# Traceback after looping through all available news article

Tags: command-line, python

I am making a python CLI utility that will answer questions like "15 + 15" or "How many letters are in the alphabet".

I then decided to add the ability to search up the latest news using the *newspaper* module.

All of it works except when the *for* loop finishes, after printing a string literal, it gives me a error that I do not know what the heck it means.

Can someone decipher the error for me and if possible, help me fix the error? Thanks.

```
import requests
import wolframalpha
import wikipedia
import time
import sys
from threading import Thread
from newspaper import Article
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

version = 2.1
build = '19w12a6'

ready = 0
loadingAnimationStop = 0

appId = 'CENSORED STUFF BECAUSE I DON\'T WANT ANYONE TO TOUCH MY KEY'
client = wolframalpha.Client(appId)

exitNow = 0

def loadingAnimation():
    while exitNow == 0:
        print("Loading: |", end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while ready == 1:
            time.sleep(0)
        print("Loading: /", end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while ready == 1:
            time.sleep(0)
        print("Loading: -", end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while ready == 1:
            time.sleep(0)
        sys.stdout.write("Loading: \ \r")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while ready == 1:
            time.sleep(0)

hui = Thread(target = loadingAnimation, args=())
hui.start()

def search_wiki(keyword=''):
    searchResults = wikipedia.search(keyword)
    if not searchResults:
        print("No result from Wikipedia")
        return
    try:
        page = wikipedia.page(searchResults[0])
    except wikipedia.DisambiguationError:
        page = wikipedia.page(err.options[0])
    wikiTitle = str(page.title.encode('utf-8'))
    wikiSummary = str(page.summary.encode('utf-8'))
    print('              ', end='\r')
    print(wikiTitle)
    print(wikiSummary)


def search(text=''):
    res = client.query(text)
    if res['@success'] == 'false':
        ready = 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Query cannot be resolved')
    else:
        result = ''
        pod0 = res['pod'][0]
        pod1 = res['pod'][1]

    if (('definition' in pod1['@title'].lower()) or ('result' in  pod1['@title'].lower()) or (pod1.get('@primary','false') == 'True')):
        result = resolveListOrDict(pod1['subpod'])
        ready = 1
        time.sleep(0.75)
        print('              ', end='\r')
        print(result)
        question = resolveListOrDict(pod0['subpod'])
        question = removeBrackets(question)
        #primaryImage(question)
    else:
        question = resolveListOrDict(pod0['subpod'])
        question = removeBrackets(question)
        search_wiki(question)


def removeBrackets(variable):
    return variable.split('(')[0]

def resolveListOrDict(variable):
    if isinstance(variable, list):
        return variable[0]['plaintext']
    else:
        return variable['plaintext']

#def primaryImage(title=''):
#    url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
#    data = {'action':'query', 'prop':'pageimages','format':'json','piprop':'original','titles':title}
#    try:
#        res = requests.get(url, params=data)
#        key = res.json()['query']['pages'].keys()[0]
#        imageUrl = res.json()['query']['pages'][key]['original']['source']
#        print(imageUrl)
#    except Exception:
#        print('Exception while finding image:= '+str(err))

page = requests.get('https://www.wolframalpha.com/')

s = page.status_code

if (s != 200):
    ready = 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print('It looks like https://www.wolframalpha.com/ is not online.')
    print('Please check your connection to the internet and https://www.wolframalpha.com/')
    print('Stopping Python Information Engine')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

page = requests.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')

s = page.status_code

if (s != 200):
    ready = 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print('It looks like https://www.wikipedia.org/ is not online.')
    print('Please check your connection to the internet and https://www.wikipedia.org/')
    print('Stopping Python Information Engine')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

ready = 1

while exitNow == 0:
    print('================================================================================================')
    print('Python Information Engine CLI Version', end=' ')
    print(version)
    print('Create by Unsigned_Py')
    print('================================================================================================')
    ready = 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print('                                                                                                ', end='\r')
    print('       ', end='\r')
    q = input('Search: ')
    print('================================================================================================')
    if (q == 'Credits()'):
        print('Credits')
        print('================================================================================================')
        print('PIE is made by Unsigned_Py')
        print('Unsigned_Py on the Python fourms: https://python-forum.io/User-Unsigned-Py')
        print('Contact Unsigned_Py: Ckyiu@outlook.com')
    if (q == 'Latest News'):
        print('DISCLAIMER: The Python Information Engine News port is still in DEVELOPMENT!')
        print('Getting latest news links from Google News...')
        ready = 0
       
        news_url = "https://news.google.com/news/rss"
        Client = urlopen(news_url)
        xml_page = Client.read()
        Client.close()

        soup_page = soup(xml_page,"xml")
        news_list = soup_page.findAll("item")
        
        ready = 1
        
        print('================================================================================================')
        
        article_number = 1
        
        for news in news_list:
            print(article_number, end=': ')
            print(news.title.text)
            print(news.pubDate.text)
            if (input('Read (Y or N)? ') == 'y'):
                ready = 0
                url = news.link.text
                article = Article(url)

                article.download()
                article.parse()

                article.nlp()
                
                ready = 1
                
                print('================================================================================================')
                print(article.summary)
            print('================================================================================================')
            article_number = article_number + 1
        
        
        print("That's all for today!")
    
    if (q == 'Version()'):
        print('Python Information Engine CLI Version', end=' ')
        print(version)
        print('Running Build', end=' ')
        print(build)
        print('Upon finding a bug, please report to Unsigned_Py and I will try to fix it!')
        print('Looking for Python Information Engine CLI Version 1.0 - 1.9?')
        print("It's called Wolfram|Alpha and Wikipedia Engine Search!")

    if (q != 'Exit()'):
        if (q != 'Credits()'):
            if (q != 'News'):
                if (q != 'Version()'):
                    ready = 0
                    search(q)
    else:
        exitNow = 1

print('Thank you for using Python Information Engine')
print('================================================================================================')
time.sleep(2)
ready = 0
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Information Engine 2.1.py", line 210, in <module>
    search(q)
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Information Engine 2.1.py", line 62, in search
    res = client.query(text)
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 56, in query
    return Result(resp)
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 178, in __init__
    super(Result, self).__init__(doc)
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 62, in __init__
    self._handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\ckyiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wolframalpha\__init__.py", line 69, in _handle_error
    raise Exception(template.format(**self))
Exception: Error 0: Unknown error
```

Comment: After this statement is where I got the error above: print("That's all for today!") @Scott, I am working on the mvce, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it to work now, for some reason I put: `if (q != 'News'):` I wanted `if (q != 'Latest News'):`.

Then python threw me a error for that. I got it to work at least now.